# If $x^3 + \frac{1}{x^3} = 2\sqrt{5}$, then find $x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

**Question**:  If $x$ is a real number satisfying $x^3 + \frac{1}{x^3} = 2\sqrt{5}$, determine the exact value of $x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}$.

**My partial solution**: $(x + \frac{1}{x})^3 = x^3 + 3x + \frac{3}{x} + \frac{1}{x^3}.$

We know that $x^3 + \frac{1}{x^3} = 2\sqrt5 \Longrightarrow (x + \frac{1}{x})^3 = 2\sqrt5 + 3x + \frac{3}{x}.$

So, $(x + \frac{1}{x})^3 = 2\sqrt5 + 3(x + \frac{1}{x})$. Let $y = x + \frac{1}{x}$.

Then, $y^3 = 2\sqrt5 + 3y$. We want to solve for $x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}$. $(x + \frac{1}{x})^2 = x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2} + 2$.

So, we want to solve for $y^2 - 2$. But, I'm confused about how to solve the equation $y^3 = 2\sqrt5 + 3y$, should I check random values?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance! (Thanks for the suggestions in the comments :)

Comment: If you set $y=x^3$, then you get a quadratic equation in $y$.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Oh yeah, I didn't think about doing it that way.

Comment: By inspection, $y=\sqrt 5$ works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}=2\sqrt{5}$ we get $\left(x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}\right)^2=20$ or $x^6+\frac{1}{x^6}=18$

Let $y=x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}$. Then $y^3 = 3y + x^6+\frac{1}{x^6} = 3y +18.$
The only real solution of $y^3-3y-18=0$ is $y=3$. Therefore $x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}=3.$

By the way, $x = \frac{\sqrt{5}\pm 1}{2}$ can be used to see that this is actually the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the comments, I now realize that from the equation $x^3 + \frac{1}{x^3} = 2\sqrt5$, if we let $z = x^3$, then we get $z + \frac{1}{z} = 2\sqrt5 \Longrightarrow z^2 + 1 - 2\sqrt5z = 0 \Longrightarrow$ using the quadratic formula, we get $z = \sqrt5 \pm 2$. Hence, from here, we can get that the answer is $5 - 2 = 3$.

I could have also tried different values of $y$ to get $\sqrt5$ as the answer.

Comment: I believe you forgot to square something. The actual answer is $x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2} = y^2 - 2 = 5 - 2 = 3$.